# Seach API Solr database service

Tags: search

I have a Drupal 7 installation on Linux with Tomcat 6 and Apache Solr.

Drupal can connect to Apache Solr, but the search only works for the "database service" class, even though I used the same settings when I created the server with "Solr Service" class.

Is there any way to troubleshoot the Solr index directly from linux box or Tomcat?

Comment: i think i took schema and solrconfing from a different module called "apachesolr" which is not compatible with seach api

Answer (score 1):

Does `{Your drupal site}/admin/config/search/search_api` show a "working" (Green tick/check mark) next to your server settings? If so press 'edit' and this should provide you with a connection link to your solr installation being served by tomcat.  The URL should be something like

> http://{IP of server with Solr on}:8080/solr

If in a browser you do to `http://{IP of server with Solr on}:8080/solr/admin` you should see a solr web query page that will allow you to query the solr server directly.

This should help indicate if solr is indexing the drupal content or not.  On my localhost server a URL to return everything would be

> 127.0.0.1:8080/solr/select/?q=*%3A*&version=2.2&start=0&rows=10&indent=on

In the event you can't contact the tomcat server (And assuming your firewall is correctly configured, not all systems allow 8080 through by default) I found the [article](http://drupal.org/node/716632) very helpful for installing and configuring Solr on Tomcat 6.